Kernel verifier complains when copying multiple UDP payload segments
I´m trying to implement a XDP/eBPF program that modifies the ingress packet in such a way that only application-relevant parts of UDP payload are kept from the ingress packet and forwarded to the system for further processing. To make the program "manageable" for the kernel verifier, I´ve divided the program into several procedures invoked by using bpf_tail_call() function call. One of these procedures copies the relevant UDP payload parts before the packet length is trimmed with "bpf_xdp_adjust_tail". The problem arises from the fact that current code implementation cannot support copying more than 2 relevant parts before kernel verifier complains that the program is too complex and that the program verification could not fit into a limit of 1 million instructions:
Kernel Verifier Error Message
´The code implementation is as follows:
SEC("xdp")
int xdp_copy_loop(struct xdp_md *ctx)
{
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;
    void *data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;

    __u32 numRelPkts, currMemSeg, currRelPkt = 0;
    __u32 action = XDP_ABORTED;
    __u32 key = 0;
    __u32 *value;

    /* Read from a respective map number of relevant "packets" inside of the UDP payload */
    value = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&numRelPkts_map, &key);

    if(!value)
        return -1;
    else
    {
        numRelPkts = *value;
        /* Make sure that "numRelPkts" variable does not exceed maximal expected value. Should help kernel verifier as well */
        if (numRelPkts > MAX_NUM_REL_PKTS)
            return -1;
    }

    copy_t* pktCopyPos = (copy_t*)&pktCopyArray[0];

    /* The section below is memcpy-like implemenation with two parameters that are provided by the caller function 
     *      .offset: defines the offset from where does the relevant UDP payload part starts
     *      .len: defines the length of the relevant UDP payload part
     */
    for(currRelPkt = 0; currRelPkt < numRelPkts; currRelPkt++)
    {
        copy_t* pktPos = (copy_t*)((__u8*)data + FIXED_UDP_PAYLOAD_OFFSET + (__u8)pktEntryArray[currRelPkt].offset);

        for(currMemSeg = 0; currMemSeg < (pktEntryArray[currRelPkt].len / sizeof(copy_t)); currMemSeg++)
        {
            if (pktPos + 1 > data_end)
                return -1;

            *pktCopyPos++ = *pktPos++;
        }
    }

    action = XDP_PASS;

    return action;
}

I´ve tried already quite some number of modifications to the code above in hope to reduce the number of instructions needed by kernel verifier. Yes, even using "__builtin_memcpy()" as well. Currently, when there is 1 relevant UDP payload part, the kernel verifier requires 912 instructions:
Kernel Verifier message with 1 relevant part
Once 2 relevant UDP payload parts are present, the number of required instructions increases to 54491:
Kernel Verifier message with 2 relevant parts
However, when attempting loading program with 3 relevant UDP payload parts, the verification could not be successfully completed with the error log already posted.
As I still learning when it comes to XDP and eBPF in general, it would be much appreciated if I could get some advice or ideas from more experienced developers. Is there some trick to further optimize the code so it can support more relevant parts or the iteration over packet segments that are of various size and number (not known during compile time, "as they come") is not ideal XDP use case.
Some additional constraints:

UDP payload is not fixed and known beforehand (==> the information is extracted from UDP header in caller function during run-time)

UDP payload can consist of 1 or multiple "mini-packets" (parts); again, not fixed nor known beforehand (the information is extracted in caller function during run-time)

Each relevant part can be of various size; again, not fixed nor known beforehand (the information is extracted in caller function during run-time)

The program is supposed to run on kernel v5.12, therefore, no bpf_loop() implemenation is possible


Thank you for your time and patience to go through complete question.

The error messages you shared are not the helpful part. It would be better if you share the log as text instead of image. Maybe sharing the last 10 line of each error log be enough.
